# When was the Sarasvata Kalpa?

Tags: puranas, bhagavata-purana, kalpa

According to the *Matysa Purana*, the events of the *Srimad Bhagavatam* took place during the *Sarasvata Kalpa*.

[image]

When was the *Sarasvata Kalpa*? Currently, we're in the *Sveta Varaha Kalpa*.

And who is it referring to by "degraded men"?

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88639/discussion-on-question-by-ikshvaku-when-was-the-sarasvata-kalpa).

Answer (score 3):

Saraswata Kalpa is as same as Sveta Varaha Kalpa only.

In the [Mahabharata 12:350 (Shanti Parva)](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c049.htm), previous birth of Vyasa is narrated. After Brahma was created from the navel of Narayana, the goddess of intelligence (Buddhi) upon the orders of Narayana entered into Brahma, then Brahma finished the creation. Thereafter Vishnu decided to incarnate in the earth whenever Adharma arises.

> After this, the original Creator of the universe once more uttered the
>   syllable, Bho, causing the atmosphere to resound with it. **From this
>   syllable of speech (Saraswati) arose a Rishi of the name Saraswat. The
>   son, thus born of the Speech of Narayana, came to be, also called by
>   the name of Apantara-tamas.** Endued with great puissance, he was fully
>   conversant with the past, the present, and the future. Firm in the
>   observance of vows, he was truthful in speech. Unto that Rishi who, after
>   birth, had bowed his head unto Narayana, the latter, who was the
>   original Creator of all the deities and possessed of a nature that was
>   immutable, said those words: Thou shouldst devote thy attention to the
>   distribution of the Vedas, O foremost of all persons endued with
>   intelligence. Do thou, therefore, O ascetic, accomplish what I
>   command thee.In obedience to this command of the Supreme Lord from
>   whose Speech the Rishi Apantaratamas sprang into existence, the
>   latter, in the Manvantara `K.M Ganguli wrongly translated this as "in the Kalpa" instead of "in the Manvantara"` named after the Self-born Manu(swayambhu Manu), distributed and
>   arranged the Vedas. For that act of the Rishi, the illustrious Hari
>   became gratified with him, as also for his well-performed penances,
>   his vow and observances, and his restraint of the senses or passions.
>   Addressing him,
>
> Narayana said, **At each Manwantara, O son, thou wilt
>   act in this way with respect to the Vedas.** Thou shalt, in consequence
>   of this act of thine, be immutable, O regenerate one, and incapable of
>   being transcended by any one. **When the Kali age will set in, certain
>   princes of Bharata's line, to be called by the name of Kauravas, will
>   take their birth from thee. They will be celebrated over the Earth as
>   high-souled princes ruling over powerful kingdoms. Born of thee,
>   dissensions will break out among them ending in their destruction at
>   one another's hands excepting yourself. O foremost of regenerate
>   persons, in that age also, endued with austere penances, thou wilt
>   distribute the Vedas into diverse classes.** **Indeed, in that dark age,
>   thy complexion will become dark.**
>
> Thou shalt cause diverse kinds of
>   duties to flow and diverse kinds of knowledge also. Although endued
>   with austere penances, yet thou shalt never be able to free thyself
>   from desire and attachment to the world. Thy son, however, will be
>   freed from every attachment like unto the Supreme Soul, through the
>   grace of Madhava. It will not be otherwise. He whom learned Brahmanas
>   call the mind-born son of the Grandsire, viz., **Vasishtha endued with
>   great intelligence and like unto an ocean of penances, and whose
>   splendour transcends that of the Sun himself, will be the progenitor
>   of a race in which a great Rishi of the name of Parasara, possessed of
>   mighty energy and prowess, will take his birth. That foremost of
>   persons, that ocean of Vedas, that abode of penances, will become thy
>   sire (when thou wilt take birth in the Kali age). Thou shalt take thy
>   birth as the son of a maiden residing in the house of her sire,
>   through an act of congress with the great Rishi Parasara.** Doubts thou wilt have none with respect to the imports of things past,
>   present, and future. Endued with penances and instructed by me, thou
>   wilt behold the incidents of thousands and thousands of ages long past
>   away. Thou wilt see through thousands and thousands of ages also in
>   the future. Thou shalt, in that birth, behold me, O ascetic,--me that
>   am without birth and death,--incarnated on Earth (as Krishna of Yadu's
>   race), armed with the discus. All this will happen to thee, O ascetic,
>   through the merit that will be thine in consequence of thy ceaseless
>   devotion to me. These words of mine will never be otherwise.
>
> Thou
>   shalt be one of the foremost of creatures. Great shall be thy fame.
>   **Surya's son Sani (Saturn) will, in a future Kalpa, take birth as the
>   great Manu of that period.** During that Manwantara, O son, thou shalt,
>   in respect of merits, be superior to even the Manus of the several
>   periods. Without doubt, thou shalt be so through my grace. Whatever
>   exists in the world represents the result of my exertion. The thoughts
>   of others may not correspond with their acts. As regards myself,
>   however, I always ordain what I think, without the least impediment!
>   Having said these words unto the Rishi Apantaratamas, otherwise called
>   by the name of Saraswat, the Supreme Lord dismissed him, saying unto
>   him. Go. **I am he that was born as Apantaratamas through the command
>   of Hari. Once more have I taken birth as the celebrated
>   Krishna-Dwaipayana, a delighter of the race of Vasishtha.** I have thus
>   told you, my dear disciples, the circumstances, of my own former birth
>   which was due to the grace of Narayana in so much that I was a very
>   portion of Narayana himself.

### Summary

- The creator of the universe uttered the    syllable of speech
  (Saraswati). From that syllable arosed a Rishi    named Saraswat, who
  was called by the name  Apantara-tamas.
- He in the    Swayambhu manvantara distributed the Vedas. Because of
  this, Lord    Narayana became very happy and said to him that
  Saraswat will be born    in the Kali Yuga when Kauravas take birth.
  Narayana also said in that    birth his complexion will be
  dark(krishna Dwaipayana).
- Narayana said    he will be born in the lineage of Vasishtha to
  Parashara, (We all    know that Vyasa was the son of Parashara) in
  the Manvantara when sun    god vivasvan's son Shani (i.e.,
  vaivaswata) will be the Manu.

### Conclusion

The current Kalpa is called Sveta Varaha Kalpa because Varaha Avatar of Vishnu happened in the beginning of this Kalpa. Similarly, in the beginning of this Kalpa, a Rishi named Saratwata was born which was the previous birth of Vyasa of 28th Dwaparayuga of Vaisvasvata Manvantara, because of 
 which this kalpa is called Saraswata Kalpa.

Comment: K.M Ganguli wrongly translated this as "in the Kalpa" instead of "in the Manvantara" --- Whose words are those? yours?

Comment: Okay, then this proves the point of @RaRe

Answer (score 1):

According to Srimadbhagavam, the thirty kalpas of Brahmā are:

Śveta-kalpa,
Nīlalohita,
Vāmadeva,
Gāthāntara,
Raurava,
Prāṇa,
Bṛhat-kalpa,
Kandarpa,
Sadyotha,
Īśāna,
Dhyāna,
Sārasvata,
Udāna,
Garuḍa,
Kaurma,
Nārasiḿha,
Samādhi,
Āgneya,
Viṣṇuja,
Saura,
Soma-kalpa,
Bhāvana,
Supuma,
Vaikuṇṭha,
Arciṣa,
Valī-kalpa,
Vairāja,
Gaurī-kalpa,
Māheśvara,
Paitṛ-kalpa.

The names of 30 Kalpas are found in the Matsya Purāṇa (290.3-12). These are:

Śveta
Nīlalohita
Vāmadeva
Rathantara
Raurava
Deva
Vṛhat
Kandarpa
Sadya
Iśāna
Tamah
Sārasvata
Udāna
Gāruda
Kaurma
Nārasiṃha
Samāna
Āgneya
Soma
Mānava
Tatpumān
Vaikuṇṭha
Lakṣmī
Sāvitrī
Aghora
Varāha
Vairaja
Gaurī
Māheśvara and
Pitṛ
The Vāyu Purāṇa in chapter 21 gives a different list of 28 kalpas. It also lists five more kalpas in the next chapter.

In the Skanda Purana, Brahma's thirty days are mentioned:

Sveta Varaha Kalpa
Nilalohita Kalpa
Vamadeva Kalpa
Gathantara Kalpa
Raurava Kalpa
Prana Kalpa
Brhat Kalpa
Kandarpa Kalpa
Sadyata Kalpa
Isana Kalpa
Dhyana Kalpa
Sarasvata Kalpa
Udana Kalpa
Garuda Kalpa
Kaurma Kalpa
Narasimha Kalpa
Samadhi Kalpa
Agneya Kalpa
Visnuja Kalpa
Saura Kalpa
Soma Kalpa
Bhavana Kalpa
Supuma Kalpa
Vaikuntha Kalpa
Arcisa Kalpa
Vali Kalpa
Vairaja Kalpa
Gauri Kalpa
Mahesvara Kalpa
Paitr Kalpa
(Source): WikiPedia

So Sarasvata and svetabaraha are two different kalpas.

Comment: Curiously, each kalpa is a day of Lord Brahma. He lives for a 100 years by that order of time. So how come only 15 kalpas are named and others are left out? I have heard of a swarna varaha kalpa as well. So, obviously, there is a chance that the reference you have given is not complete.

Comment: @Ambi i have nentioned the names of 30 kalpas

Comment: Matsya Purana in chapter 290 mentions Sveta, Varaha and Saraswata Kalpa separately. http://hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/matsya-mahapurana/vol-ii/chapter-290/topic-1

Comment: @NaveenKick Maybe Sveta is one Kalpa, Varaha is another Kalpa, and Sveta Varaha is altogether another Kalpa?

Comment: @Ikshvaku No. i think its one. total count including purnima and amabasya is okay

Comment: @Ikshvaku Sveta Varaha Kalpa is not at all mentioned in the matsya Purana. Sveta kalpa and Varaha Kalpa both are separately mentioned.

Comment: @Ambi Kalpa names are names of Mahakalpa. Sometimes Mahakalpa is used as Kalpa.